# Reflect update setInterval(function()) in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, redux

I'm wondering that there is a way I can make an api call with an interval and update my view whenever there is a change in api data.

part of my code looks like..

index.ios.js

```
....
import App from './src/components/app';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import { getData } from './src/actions/index';

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise, ReduxThunk)));
store.dispatch(getData());

class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent.....
```

So the `store.dispatch(getData())` initially make an api call and I can display the data using redux (this.props.data..something like this) in my containers.

I tried to make an api call with an interval like `store.dispatch(setInterval(getData()), 30000)` but it gives me an error saying `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'func.apply')`

If anyone has had this kind of issue before or knows what to do in this situation, please let me know.

Thanks for your support in advanced.

Comment: try putting `setInterval` outside of `dispatch`

Comment: Have you considered using another middleware for orchestrating your side-effects? I usually use [`redux-saga`](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/) which has a pretty nice way [to subscribe to external events by using eventChannels](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events). I'm pretty bias against redux-thunk/redux-promise.

Comment: @MattWay I tried but it gave me the same error.

Comment: @Josep Never used that before. I will take a look. Thanks :)

Comment: @MattWay Actually, nvm. I played around with setInterval and got it to work. Thank you so much!!